# gedit “cannot open display” , on remote OSX , using ssh - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Profile

Tags: 14.04, ssh, gedit

I am getting the following error message when using ssh to log into a remote machine:

```
gedit: cannot open display
```

and

```
ssh -X -l root your-machine-name
```

does not work

```
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
           [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]
           [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           [user@]hostname [command]
```

Comment: Actually _read_ the usage of ssh. Try "ssh -X -l root@your-machine-name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though you have a program set up too automatically run GEDIT when starting a shell (Or you're trying to open it). This won't work via ssh because you don't have an X-Server running in your current session.

As for the issue with running `ssh -X -l root your-machine-name` your copy of ssh wasn't compiled to support the `-X` option

Basically you:

1. Need an X-Server running in your session
2. Need to recompile `ssh` with support for `-X` optioon